# pandas- calculate percentile (quantile) of grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas, quantile, percentile

My dataframe looks like

```
lang score
en    0.7
fr    0.4
en    0.3
...
it    0.7
fr    0.2
de    0.5
...
```

I want to get the percentile (Pandas `quantile`) of the `score` col grouped by the `lang` col, so I calculate mean, median and percentile as follows:

```
mean = df.groupby('lang')['score'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)
median = df.groupby('lang')['score'].median().sort_values(ascending=False)
perc = df.groupby('lang')['score'].quantile(np.linspace(.1, 1, 9, 0))
```

While `mean` and `median` are correct, I get a `NaN` for the quantile col:

```
fr                       0.1                    NaN
                         0.2                    NaN
                         0.3                    NaN
                         0.4                    NaN
                         0.5                    NaN
...                                             ...
en                       0.5                    NaN
                         0.6                    NaN
                         0.7                    NaN
                         0.8                    NaN
                         0.9                    NaN
```

Where is the error?

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you need to update your Pandas.

Comment: @MykolaZotko thank you. I'm using latest `numpy==1.18.5` and `pandas` latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you have NaNs in your dataframe?

Try executing this before the perc computation:

```
df.dropna(subset=['score'])
```